# Save a dynamic data set using AJAX in MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, razor, callback, devexpress

I have a razor view in which I generate the controls on the page generically by using a foreach loop on a list of data from a database.  I am using DevExpress for my controls but I don't think that matters too much for solving this problem.

```
var docTypes = MyProject.GetDocumentTypes();
foreach(var docType in docTypes)
{
    //Add controls (Example Control Below)
    groupItem.Items.Add(i =>
       {
          i.Name = "checkDoc" + docType.Id;
          i.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.CheckBox;
       });
}
```

Usually when I write an AJAX call to save this data, I would write something like this.  Note that this is being called when clicking a save button specifically:

```
function updateDocs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveDocs", "Home")',
        data: {
            key: '@(Model.Id)',
            docChecked: checkDoc1.GetValue(),
        }, success: function(data){
        },
        error: function(data){
        }
    });
}
```

Then with the method:

```
    public JsonResult SaveDocs(int key, bool docChecked)
    {
        //Save the data here
        return Json(new { isSuccess = true },
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        );
    }
```

However, if I am generating the controls at runtime, I cannot know what exactly there is to pull for my parameters for the data section.

I was thinking that if I could somehow get this data into a Dictionary or something then I could pass it generically to a function with a parameter that accepts that Dictionary.  If I can pass just some key data points to my Controller I can figure out how to save it from there.  I would just need the value that the control holds and the control name itself passed in the simplest solution.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this problem.

Comment: have you looked at this post: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T344346/find-control-by-name-in-javascript-and-access-its-events

Comment: That is some good information, but I'm not sure how it helps with this issue in particular.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can use this (this allows you to send any number of params of any type and parse them in the Action)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostData(dynamic postData)
{
            Dictionary<string,string> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)postData)["data"].ToString());
...........
}
```

Or just send a dictionary

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostData(Dictionary<string,string> postData)
    {
                 .......
    }
```

The js call (for dynamic data type)

```
$http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: Helper.ApiUrl() + '...',
                    data: { customer, applicant, accountNumber,... },
                })
```